# Data Loss Prevention on Big Data files

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have migrated a big data application on to cloud and the input files are stored in GCS. The files can be of different formats like txt, csv, avro, parquet etc and these files contain sensitive data that I want to mask.

Also, I have read there is some quota restriction on the size of file. For my case a single file can contain 15M records.

I have tried the DLP UI as well as Client library to inspect those files, but its not working.

Github page - https://github.com/Hitman007IN/DataLossPreventionGCPDemo

under the resources there are 2 files. test.txt is working and test1.txt which is the sample file that I use in my application is not working.

Comment: What's your question, and what's do you need for help ?

Comment: I tried 2 set of files, one is a sentence containing phone number and email address, this I was able to mask. But the other file contains some 5 records in a tabular format, that contains email address and phone number which DLP was not able to detect.

So, My question here is how to mask sensitive data on google cloud storage with cloud DLP.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud DLP just launched support last week for scanning Avro files natively.